# Tumblr shows empty iframe when embedding video

Tags: youtube, tumblr, video

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video into a text post on my Tumblr blog. I copied the HTML from YouTube and pasted it into the HTML of the post, but when I preview it, the video doesn't show up. In the code, the `src` attribute of the iframe is being nullified. So, all I see is an empty iframe on the page without the video.

Is there any reason why this is happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: A link to your tumblr page and theme and/or source code would go a long way in making this a more answerable question.